# Executing code within Org mode `begin_src` ... `end_src` blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

How to configure Emacs to run code in different languages as shown in this [post](http://howardism.org/Technical/Emacs/literate-devops.html)?
Specifically, how to run these type of code blocks `#+begin_src shell :results list` ?

After 9 years of vim, that post inspired me to try Emacs. What attracts me is the ability to run a wide range of code within Emacs. I successfully configured Emacs to run in Evil mode with the keybinding I prefer, but I still have difficulties to find how to make it work as demonstrated in the post.

Comment: Sure, the question should be specific. When you are a beginner -- formulating the right question is the majority of the effort. The responses below are exactly what I needed.

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example you pointed to (as you probably already know) require a certain amount of configuration, and also require understanding of certain concept in order to figure out what is going on.

I'm going to execute a trivial shell code block in an emacs after ensuring that I am not relying on any of my personal emacs configuration

Concepts:

- Skip emacs configuration: run emacs as "emacs -q bar.org"
- Org mode buffer - most emacs configs will auto-assign the editing behaviour for 
  a buffer based on the file extension.  So the fact that the file I visit is 
  ends in ".org" is critical.
- Org babel - this is the function (which allows execution of an embedded code 
  block) that we are using.  The manual is at https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html#fn.1

Steps:

1. emacs -q bar.org
2. Enable handling of shell blocks by executing a lisp expression:

   - Type in `(org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages '((shell . t)))`
   - Execute this block by type `C-x C-e` or `M-x eval-last-sexp`
3. Add example shell call:

   `#+begin_src shell :results list

    ls /etc/pam.d

    #+end_src`
4. Execute this block.  Use the key sequence `C-c C-c` for this.

Result:

If you are on a linux (or maybe mac), you should see a list of the contents of a
directory.

Comment: Thank you for steps that are easy to reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to emacs!
I recommend you to check the official org documentation about the evaluation of code blocks [here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Working-with-Source-Code.html#Working-with-Source-Code).

So, the thing to use is `org-babel`, to evaluate the source code inside org-mode blocks, babel has a default list of languages that can be used out of the box.

If one on the languages is not in there, you can try looking for it in [MELPA](https://melpa.org) or in [ELPA](https://elpa.gnu.org/), for example, the ipython babel is on MELPA.

So the quick answer is, define the code blocks and evaluate the buffer with:

```lisp
M-x org-babel-execute-buffer
```

You can do that by typing `C-c C-c` anywhere within the code block. For example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results output
echo "hi"
#+END_SRC


#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results output
(print "hello again")
#+END_SRC
```

If the command is successful, there will be a `#+RESULTS:` block with the
actual result after the evaluated code block.

Good luck!

Comment: `ob-python.el` is part of Org mode (and part of emacs). You do not have to get it from MELPA or ELPA. And I should point out that there is no substitute to reading the Org mode documentation (not just the part about "Working with source code").

Comment: Right! I was thinking of the  ob-ipython package with jupyter, my bad

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the useful links within!